# ¿Cómo guardar valores nulos?

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando guardar datos nulos, pero cuando los mando con la instrucción me los manda vacíos, este es mi código para insertarlos en SQL Server:

```
public Boolean DetalleLote(int Programa, int Lote, int? T150, int? T155, int? T160, int? T165, int? T170, int? T175, int? T180, int? T185, int? T190, int? T195, int? T200, int? T205, int? T210, int? T215, int? T220, int? T225, int? T230, int? T235, int? T240, int? T245, int? T250, int? T255, int? T260, int? T265, int? T270, int? T275, int? T280, int? T285, int? T290, int? T295, int? T300, int Cantidad)
    {
        try
        {
            String query = "INSERT INTO DetalleLote VALUES(" + Programa + ", " + Lote + ", " + T150 + ", " + T155 + ", " + T160 + ", " + T165 + ", " + T170 + ", " + T175 + ", " + T180 + ", " + T185 + ", " + T190 + ", " + T195 + ", " + T200 + ", " + T205 + ", " + T210 + ", " + T215 + ", " + T220 + ", " + T225 + ", " + T230 + ", " + T235 + ", " + T240 + ", " + T245 + ", " + T250 + ", " + T255 + ", " + T260 + ", " + T265 + ", " + T270 + ", " + T275 + ", " + T280 + ", " + T285 + ", " + T290 + ", " + T295 + ", " + T300 + ", " + Cantidad + ")";
            daccess.insert(query);
            return true;                
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Pero cuando los mando a guardar me manda el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he checado el resultado y me manda los o campos vacíos, como aqui:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no los quiero vacíos, los quiero nulos, si me pudieran ayudar a resolver este pequeño problema, por favor

Comment: Si. No hagas de esa forma. Hace un insert into (campo1, campo2,campo3...) values (valor1, valor2, valor3).. De esa forma todo el resto quedan nulos por defecto. te recomendaria que leas sobre la clausula insert into de tu DB. y tu problema no es en c#, es en sql

Comment: Así es, pero me arroja error porque los datos llegan vacíos, por lo tanto el sql va a mandar error, porque faltan datos por mandarle, pero no encuentro el error, por que al momento de cargar los datos en el "String query" los datos me los vuelve vacíos, antes de pasarlos a esa instrucción el visual studio me dice que son null

Comment: Si tu tabla no acepta valores nulos, es debido a la restricción NOT NULL, cambia esto en los campos de la tabla a la cual quieres enviarle valores nulos.

Comment: la tabla la tengo para que acepte valores nulos

Comment: Solo pasa los campos que no sean nulos... y no vas a tener problema...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se que haces dentro de `daccess.insert()` pero si este no permite definir parametros entonces no lo uses o modificalo

Tu codigo deberia tener esta estructura

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Cadena de conexión"))
{
    cn.Open();

    string query = @"INSERT INTO DetalleLote (programa, lote, T150, T155, ...) 
                     VALUES (@Programa, @Lote, @T150, @T155, ...)";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Programa", Programa);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lote", Lote);

    if(T150.HasValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T150", T150.Value);
    else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T150", DBNUll.Value);

    if(T155.HasValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T155", T155.Value);
    else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T155", DBNUll.Value);

    //agregar todos los parámetros

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

- No se concatenan en un string los valores que quieres insertar
- Debes definir los campos en el insert, es una buena practica

La idea es que evalues si el parametro tiene valor o no y asignes un `DBNUll.Value` al parametro

Comment: Estoy programando en 3 capas, por eso tiene la instrucción [daccess.insert(query)], con esa instrucción la mando a un método en otra capa para insertar los datos, ¿Hay alguna manera de implementar esto que me pones de la manera en que lo estoy haciendo?

Comment: ese query.insert() no es programar en capas, es solo una clase helper que abastrae la funcionalidad del insert, pero no con capas. Analiza este articulo http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2011/02/winforms-edicion-empleados-grabar.html  ali explico como son las capas, solo que usando sql server, pero aplica a cualquier db